# Polymer core-selector - using the selected data

Tags: polymer

I am building a custom element to read files in a given directory (e.g. ini files from a /config directory) and display them as a list wrapped in a core-selector. The user can then select a file from the list.
All works fine except reading the selected data seems clumsy. The relevant code is:

```
<div>
        <core-selector on-core-activate={{getFileSelected}} selected="">
            <template repeat="{{file in files}}">

                <rnc-commandfilelist>
                    <span class="rnc-fileindex">{{file.index}}</span>
                    <span class="rnc-filename">{{file.commandFileName}}</span>
                </rnc-commandfilelist>

            </template>
        </core-selector>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
    Polymer('rnc-getscaffoldini', {
        matchstring: ".ini",
        configurationdirectory: "configuration",

        getFileSelected: function (e, detail, sender) {
            var fileSelected = detail.item.children[1].innerText;
            console.log(fileSelected);

            var fullPath = this.configurationdirectory + "/" + fileSelected;

            this.setAttribute('selectedfilename', fileSelected);
            this.setAttribute('selectedfullpathname', fullPath);
        }
    });

</script>
```

The code line:

```
var fileSelected = detail.item.children[1].innerText;
```

gets the selected file name okay. Is there a better way of getting the selected data fields back?

Comment: sorry, does your code work and do you want to know if it's "good enough", or is your code actually broken?

Comment: Code works okay in Chrome 36+ IE11 and Opera 23.0 buts fails in FireFox 31.0.
In the above code Firefox returns 'undefined'.

Comment: it looks like you're missing some markup still (starting at `<polymer-element` and ending at `</polymer-element>`), could you add that so that we can see what's going on? Or that plus a jsbin with your element code to show it working in Chrome but not Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `selectedModel` property published by `core-selector` refers to the selected data model. The repeat syntax here `repeat="{{file in files}}">` means that each item has a data model that contains the scope data plus a property called `file`. That means for each item, the selected file is stored in the selector as `selectedModel.file`. You can use binding to access the data.

So, if you do:

```
<core-selector selectedModel="{{selectedModel}}">
```

then you can have:

```
selectedModelChanged: function() {
  // this.selectedModel.file refers to the particular file that is selected
}
```

--

Fwiw, you could also structure it this way:

```
<template repeat="{{files}}">
  <rnc-commandfilelist>
    <span class="rnc-fileindex">{{index}}</span>
```

Because of the different repeat syntax, now the data model is simply the file record, so:

```
<core-selector selectedModel="{{selectedFile}}">
```

then you can have:

```
selectedFileChanged: function() {
  // this.selectedFile refers to the particular file that is selected
}
```

http://jsbin.com/putecu/1/edit

Comment: In <core-selector selectedModel="{{selectedFile}}">, where is "{{selectedFile}}" defined?

Comment: Using `selectedFile` in a binding like that is enough to make it a property of the host, without any additional definition.

Comment: Is there a reference on the core-select API that explains how this works at a more fundamental level? The Polymer doc just leaves me in mystery. And in the Dart editor, these properties of the core-select element are not displayed unless I set explicit watches on them.